# Can not rename file (The system cannot find the file specified (code: 2))

Tags: php, rename

I'm trying to write a code that renames files in a directory (C:\BA\scrapers). In cmd you are prompted for input what file to rename ($filePointer) and then prompted for what the file name will be renamed to ($newFileName).

I am getting the following error: The system cannot find the file specified (code: 2)

```
function renameFile(){
    $filePointer = rtrim(fgets(STDIN));
    echo "\nEnter new file name: ";
    $newFileName = rtrim(fgets(STDIN));
    if(!rename($filePointer, $newFileName)){
      echo ("$filePointer cannot be renamed due to an error");
    }
    else {
      rename($filePointer, $newFileName);
    }
}
```

I've tried specifying what directory to rename in, however I didn't manage to make it work. I'm a beginner, so please go easy on me.

Answer (score 1):

You are renaming the file twice. After you renamed it in

```
if(!rename($filePointer, $newFileName)){
```

it obviously doesn't exist to rename it again in

```
else {
  rename($filePointer, $newFileName);
}
```

Remove the `else` block

Answer (score 0):

You must write something like this to make it work.

```
<?php
function renameFile(){
    
    $myPath="C:\\BA\\scrapers\\";
    echo "\nEnter old file name: ";
    $filePointer =$myPath . rtrim(fgets(STDIN));
    echo "\nEnter new file name: ";
    $newFileName = $myPath .rtrim(fgets(STDIN));
    if(!rename($filePointer, $newFileName)){
      echo ("$filePointer cannot be renamed due to an error");
    }
    else {
      echo "Successfully renamed";
    }
}
?>
```